# What to do about copied/unattributed quotes as answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

A [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/897/43) from Jan 2012 about the placement of a comma in Luke 23:43 attracted [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2472/43):

> The understanding of Luke 23:43 is influenced by the punctuation used by the translator. There was no punctuation in the original Greek Bible manuscripts. *The Encyclopedia Americana* (1956, Vol. XXIII, p. 16) states: “No attempt to punctuate is apparent in the earlier manuscripts and inscriptions of the Greeks.” Not until the 9th century C.E. did such punctuation come into use. Should Luke 23:43 read, “Truly, I say to you, today you will be with me in Paradise” (*RS*), or should it be, ‘Truly I say to you today, You will be with me in Paradise’? The teachings of Christ and the rest of the Bible must be the basis for determination, and not a comma inserted in the text centuries after Jesus said those words.
>
> *The Emphasised Bible* translated by J. B. Rotherham agrees with the punctuation in the *New World Translation*. In a footnote on Luke 23:43, German Bible translator L. Reinhardt says: “The punctuation presently used [by most translators] in this verse is undoubtedly false and contradictory to the entire way of thinking of Christ and the evildoer. . . . [Christ] certainly did not understand paradise to be a subdivision of the realm of the dead, but rather the restoration of a paradise on earth.”
>
> When would Jesus ‘get into his kingdom’ and fulfill his Father’s purpose to make the earth a paradise? The book of Revelation, written about 63 years after the statements recorded at Luke 23:42, 43 were made, indicates that these events were still in the future.

I praised the answer at the time as it appeared well thought out and researched, however, a comment from TRiG caught my eye just now:

> Am I right in guessing that this entire answer is an unattributed quote from a Watchtower publication? The writing style feels familiar. – TRiG Nov 7 '12 at 0:30

A bit of Googling uncovered this article from 'Watchtower Online' containing this text near the end:

> When will the evildoer be in Paradise?
>
> One’s understanding of Luke 23:43 is influenced by the punctuation used by the translator. There was no punctuation in the original Greek Bible manuscripts. The Encyclopedia Americana (1956, Vol. XXIII, p. 16) states: “No attempt to punctuate is apparent in the earlier manuscripts and inscriptions of the Greeks.” Not until the 9th century C.E. did such punctuation come into use. Should Luke 23:43 read, “Truly, I say to you, today you will be with me in Paradise” (RS), or should it be, ‘Truly I say to you today, You will be with me in Paradise’? The teachings of Christ and the rest of the Bible must be the basis for determination, and not a comma inserted in the text centuries after Jesus said those words.
>
> The Emphasised Bible translated by J. B. Rotherham agrees with the punctuation in the New World Translation. In a footnote on Luke 23:43, German Bible translator L. Reinhardt says: “The punctuation presently used [by most translators] in this verse is undoubtedly false and contradictory to the entire way of thinking of Christ and the evildoer. . . . [Christ] certainly did not understand paradise to be a subdivision of the realm of the dead, but rather the restoration of a paradise on earth.”
>
> When would Jesus ‘get into his kingdom’ and fulfill his Father’s purpose to make the earth a paradise? The book of Revelation, written about 63 years after the statements recorded at Luke 23:42, 43 were made, indicates that these events were still in the future. (See pages 95-98, under “Dates,” also the main heading “Last Days.”)

In other words obviously the same text with only the most minor of tweaking.

#### The question is, what should we do about it, and future similar cases? Edit to add the attribution, or something else?

Comment: Compare: [Christianity](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/154/214). Also, this has been a really big problem on Islam: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/324/156; http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/193/156; http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/369/156.